# MongoDB: Counting how many of each distinct values there are?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents holding a list of feedbacks for different items. It looks something like this:

```js
{
  {
    item: "item_1"
    rating: "neutral"
    comment: "some comment"
  },
  {
    item: "item_2"
    rating: "good"
    comment: "some comment"
  },
  {
    item: "item_1"
    rating: "good"
    comment: "some comment"
  },
  {
    item: "item_1"
    rating: "bad"
    comment: "some comment"
  },
  {
    item: "item_3"
    rating: "good"
    comment: "some comment"
  },
}
```

I want a way to find out how many different ratings each item got.

so the output should look something like this:

```js
{
  {
    item: "item_1"
    good: 12
    neutral: 10
    bad: 67
  },
  {
    item: "item_2"
    good: 2
    neutral: 45
    bad: 8
  },
  {
    item: "item_3"
    good: 1
    neutral: 31
    bad: 10
  }

}
```

This is what I've done

```
db.collection(collectionName).aggregate(
          [
             {
               $group:
                 {
                   _id: "$item",
                   good_count: {$sum: {$eq: ["$rating",  "Good"]}},
                   neutral_count:{$sum: {$eq: ["$rating",  "Neutral"]}},
                   bad_count:{$sum: {$eq: ["$rating",  "Bad"]}},
                 }
             }
           ]
)
```

The format of the output looks right, but the counts are always 0.

I'm wondering what's the properway of summing things up by looking at the distinct values of the same field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close, but of course [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) just returns a `true/false` value, so to make that numeric you need [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/):

```
db.collection(collectionName).aggregate([
  { "$group" : {
       "_id": "$item",
       "good_count": { 
           "$sum": { 
               "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$rating",  "good" ] }, 1, 0] 
           }
       },
       "neutral_count":{
           "$sum": { 
               "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$rating", "neutral" ] }, 1, 0 ]
            }
       },
       "bad_count": { 
           "$sum": { 
               "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$rating",  "bad" ] }, 1, 0 ]
           }
       }
  }}
])
```

As a "ternary" operator `$cond` takes a logical condition as it's first argument (if) and then returns the second argument where the evaluation is `true` (then) or the third argument where `false` (else). This makes `true/false` returns into `1` and `0` to feed to `$sum` respectively.

Also note that "case" is sensitive for `$eq`. If you have varing case then you likely want [`$toLower`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower/) in the expressions:

```
               "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ { "$toLower": "$rating" },  "bad" ] }, 1, 0 ]
```

---

On a slightly different note, the following aggregation is usually more flexible to different possible values and runs rings around the conditional sums in terms of performance:

```
db.collection(collectionName).aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { 
            "item": "$item",
            "rating": { "$toLower": "$rating" }
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.item",
        "results": {
            "$push": {
                "rating": "$_id.rating",
                "count": "$count"
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

That would instead give output like this:

```
{
    "_id": "item_1"
    "results":[
        { "rating": "good", "count": 12 },
        { "rating": "neutral", "count": 10 }
        { "rating": "bad", "count": 67 }
    ]
}
```

It's all the same information, but you did not have to explicitly match the values and it does execute much faster this way.